# Advantage of using @classmethod instead of type(self) in Python?

Tags: python, class, class-method

Is there an advantage in using a `@classmethod` (and `cls`) instead of `type(self)` to instantiate classes?

For example, an abstract class contains a normal method which at some point instantiates an instance of the sub-class whose instance calls that method. So the call to `type(self)` (located inside a method in the abstract base class) would be a call to the sub-class (same as, I suppose, would be if using `@classmethod`).

```
class M(ABC):
    ...
    def simple_method(self):
        'Do stuff & return new instance'
        return type(self)()

    @classmethod
    def cls_method(cls):
        return cls()

class A(M):
    ...

a = A()
b = a.simple_method()
c = a.cls_method()
```

It appears to me easier and more flexible to use `type(self)` than `@classmethod`. Is there anything against this practice or cases where it should be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are evaluating type of the object and then creating an object out of it which will be slower than using `classmethod` because `cls` is directly passed down to the function and there is no need to evaluate the type. Another difference is that to invoke a `classmethod` you do not need the object of that class to be initialized you can directly invoke it using `A.cls_method()`

Comment: Thought `type(self)` is computationally same as `self.__class__`? Would calling a classmethod `b = a.cls_method()` be less expensive than directly calling `b = type(a)()`?

Comment: type and __class__ have a few differences, it is better discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060499/difference-between-typeobj-and-obj-class, function calls add overhead as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648374/python-function-calls-are-really-slow a.cls_method() is less expensive in terms of memory footprint because you do not have an object in memory, object creation should take some time so in terms of time as well there should be a variation, but we are talking about micro optimization here, nothing significant